# how to post json in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to post data to server ,but it not posted why this happened i don't know please help me some one.Thanks in advance.

```
 NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"groupname":@"prasad",@"friends":contactsArray};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"groupsarray=%@", jsonString];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://anaadit.net/caffe/newapp/CreateGroup.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *errors = nil;



NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply options:0 error:&errors];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"response %@", responseString);
NSLog(@"request %@", request);
NSLog(@"jsonArray%@",jsonArray);
```

Edit :
Output is:
    [friends] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 8
                    [contact_no] => 555-522-8243
                    [contact_name] => AnnaHaro
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 8
                [contact_no] => 555-478-7672
                [contact_name] => DanielHiggins
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 8
                [contact_no] => 555-610-6679
                [contact_name] => DavidTaylor
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 8
                [contact_no] => (555) 766-4823
                [contact_name] => HankZakroff
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 8
                [contact_no] => 888-555-5512
                [contact_name] => JohnAppleseed
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 8
                [contact_no] => (555) 564-8583
                [contact_name] => KateBell
            )

    )
```

but i don't need this

Comment: i need to send data like this way  {
    "groupname": "Manjit",
    "friends": [
        {
            "user_id": "8",
            "contact_no": "555-522-8243",
            "contact_name": "AnnaHaro"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "8",
            "contact_no": "555-478-7672",
            "contact_name": "DanielHiggins"
        }]
}

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. Do not put it in comment, it's less readable.
In "POSTReply", you don't use the "error" parameter, and never read them! Does it works? Where exactly you have an issue ? What are the output? Is `responseData` nil? Are there values nil?

Comment: out put is:(
    [friends] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 8
                    [contact_no] => 555-522-8243
                    [contact_name] => AnnaHaro
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 8
                    [contact_no] => 555-478-7672
                    [contact_name] => DanielHiggins
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 8
                    [contact_no] => 555-610-6679

Comment: Please, put these informations by editing your question, not in comment.

Comment: ok,i will edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is invalid. A json allways starts with an object or list, but never with a property. See json.org for that. {"groupsarray":your json } but not "groupsarray":your json

```
   NSDictionary *dict=@{@"groupname": @"Manjit", @"friends": @[ @{ @"user_id": @"8", @"contact_no": @"555-522-8243", @"contact_name": @"AnnaHaro" }, @{ @"user_id": @"8", @"contact_no": @"555-478-7672", @"contact_name": @"DanielHiggins" }] };
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

...
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

alternative you could fix your string creation.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{groupsarray=%@}", jsonString];
```

But there is no point if you can create a valid object structure right away. less overhead.

Comment: thank you for reply me,it's working fine you save my day